# How to check parameter value which match with which record in mysql

Tags: mysql, select, where-clause

I have a problem to check parameter value with records value. I try to show the latest Rom Core update based on parameter. The Rom Core version sometimes have revision. There are two records to be check. Detail as below :

**Parameter:**

```
Model = DPX5000BTITA9N
Serial = 063X1200
```

**Record Value:**

```
Model           Startserial     Romcore
DPX5000BTITA9N  063X0001        SYS17-127
DPX5000BTITA9N  063X1001        SYS17-130`
```

How to check serial `063X1200` whether include in `Startserial : 063X0001 or 063X1001` cause there is nothing Endserial?

```
Select Romcore From Version WHERE model LIKE 'DPX5000BTITA9N' AND serial <= '063X1200'(check the serial match with which Startserial)
```

I expect the output `SYS17-130` cause :

```
If serial >= 063X0001 will get SYS17-127
If serial >= 063X1001 will get SYS17-130
```

But the actual output is both `SYS17-127 & SYS17-130`.

Comment: You get both because '063X0001'<'063X1200' and '063X1001'<'063X1200' too.

Comment: @nacho yes, because i confused to get Romcore `SYS17-130` using '063X1200`. Actually `If serial >= 063X0001` i will get `SYS17-127`, But `If serial >= 063X1001` i will get `SYS17-130`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you want to order the results and get the latest one?

```
Select Romcore From Version 
WHERE model LIKE 'DPX5000BTITA9N' 
AND serial <= '063X1200' 
order by serial desc 
limit 1
```

Comment: only use Order By desc and limit 1. i have tried to change serial in parameter and all work.